# How can i fix an error of displaying weather Icons in react

Tags: reactjs

*I'm creating a simple weather app using an API, but I'm using the icons from https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons, I've written the functionality to display each icon based on the value that I got from my data for each country, but I know that I missed something that is not allowing me to access to the value of the icon in my state.*

**My app component**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import InitialData from '../InitialData';
import "weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css";


const WeatherListing = () => {
    //States
    const [countryName,setCountryName] = useState(InitialData.name);
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState(InitialData.temp);
    const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = useState(InitialData.temp_max);
    const [minTemp, setMinTemp] = useState(InitialData.temp_min);
    const [WeatherDesc, setWeatherDesc] = useState(InitialData.description);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [weatherIcons, setWeatherIcons] = useState({
        Thunderstorm: "wi-thunderstorm",
        Drizzle: "wi-sleet",
        Rain: "wi-storm-showers",
        Snow: "wi-snow", 
        Atmosphere: "wi-fog",
        Clear: "wi-day-sunny",
        Clouds: "wi-day-fog"
    })
    
    

    //Display the icons based on the value
    const displayIcons = (icons, rangeId) => {
        switch(true) {
            case rangeId >=200 && rangeId < 232 :
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Thunderstorm);
                break;
            case rangeId >= 300 && rangeId <= 321: 
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Drizzle);
                break;
            case rangeId >= 500 && rangeId <= 521:
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Rain);
                break;
            case rangeId >= 600 && rangeId <= 622:
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Snow);
                break;
            case rangeId >= 701 && rangeId <= 781:
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Atmosphere);
                break;
            case rangeId === 800:
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Clear);
                break;
            case rangeId >= 801 && rangeId <= 804:
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Clouds);
                break;
            default : 
                setWeatherIcons(icons.Clouds)
        }
    }
    

    //submit function to get the data by country
    const submitCountry = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(name) {
            try {
                const fetchData = async () => {
                const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${Api_Key}`)
                const result = await response.data;
                      setCountryName(result.name);
                      setTemp(convertToCeil(result.main.temp))
                      setMaxTemp(convertToCeil(result.main.temp_max))
                      setMinTemp(convertToCeil(result.main.temp_min))
                      setWeatherDesc(result.weather[0].description)  
                      console.log(result.weather[0].id)

                      displayIcons(setWeatherIcons, result.weather[0].id)
              }
              fetchData();
              
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(`Error : ${error}`)
            }

        }
        setName("")
        
    }

    //To convert number to ceil
    const convertToCeil = (temp) =>  {
        let cell = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
        return cell
    }

    return (
        <section className="container">
            <form className="form-control" >
                <input type="text" 
                       placeholder="Search by country"
                       value={name}
                       onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}
                       />
                <button type="submit" onClick={submitCountry}>Search</button>
            </form>

            <article>
                <h1>{countryName}</h1>
                <h3>{temp}°C</h3>
                <i className={`wi ${weatherIcons}`}></i>
                <h2>{WeatherDesc}</h2>
                <h4>{maxTemp}°C<span>/</span>{minTemp}°C</h4>
            </article>
        </section>
        
    )
}

export default WeatherListing
```

**What do you think?**

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all the icons in a seperate object , like this:

```
 const icons=   {
            Thunderstorm: "wi-thunderstorm",
            Drizzle: "wi-sleet",
            Rain: "wi-storm-showers",
            Snow: "wi-snow", 
            Atmosphere: "wi-fog",
            Clear: "wi-day-sunny",
            Clouds: "wi-day-fog"
        }
```

I recommend you change the structure of your state. I'd have each weather instance to be an object, whith all your properties, one being the icon property. From there , you change that state's icon property with the state that matches in the `icons` object. What you did is you initialized the weatherIcons state with ALL your possible icon options, which is usually a really bad way to initialize a state.

Comment: Would you please demonstrate your explanation with a piece of code, Thank you Malik

Answer (score 0):

I would start by only have one piece of state that gets the data instead of having multiple pieces of state for each individual attribute you are trying to get. With one piece of state you can access all of the attributes within the Object that is returned and use it in your JSX.

This should work to get you the weather icons depending on the ID that corresponds with the current weather of the city the user searched.
Let me know if you have more questions about the code below or are having problems!

```
export default function App() {
          const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        
          const mainIcons = {
            Thunderstorm: "wi-thunderstorm",
            Drizzle: "wi-sleet",
            Rain: "wi-storm-showers",
            Snow: "wi-snow",
            Atmosphere: "wi-fog",
            Clear: "wi-day-sunny",
            Clouds: "wi-day-fog"
          };
          let apiKey = "key...";
        
          const submitCity = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        
            try {
              const res = await axios.get(
                `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`
              );
              setData(res.data);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          };
        
          
        
          
          const displayIconsById = (icon) => {
            switch (true) {
              case icon >= 200 && icon < 232:
                icon = weatherIcons.Thunderstorm;
                break;
              case icon >= 300 && icon <= 321:
                icon = weatherIcons.Rain;
                break;
        
              default:
                icon = "n/a";
            }
            return icon;
          };
        
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <h1>Get City</h1>
              <form action="submit">
                <input type="text" 
                   placeholder="Search by city"
                   value={name}
                   onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={submitCountry} type="submit">
                  SUBMIT
                </button>
              </form>
        
              <h2>{data && data.name}</h2>
              <img src={displayIconsById(data.weather && data.weather[0].id)}/>
            </div>
          );
        }
```